# How to make mod_rewrite work transparently?

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite

Following is the content of .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  Options +Indexes
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.org$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/%1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

My purpose is to map all subdomain to folders. For example if `a1.example.org` is opened it should show the content of `example.org/x1`. But the URL should not change.

But whenever I open `a1.example.org` the URL is automatically getting changed. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use absolute URLs

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1 [L]
```

Comment: This does assume that both the subdomain and the main domain point to the same place on the filesystem.

Comment: AFAIK there is a difference between $1 and %1. First comes from regexp in RewriteRule, second - in RewriteCond.

Comment: Yes, I'm not disputing that - your directives look correct. However, as stated above, this will only work if the subdomain and the main domain point to the same place (ie. to the main domain's document root) - which they often do not. So, `a1.example.com/a1` (the equivalent filesystem path) must be accessible. Just saying.

Comment: It's not the same place, but subfolder ;), but yes - you have a point here

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a reverse proxy. Fortunately, there's a [flag to do this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p).

So you need to enable `mod_proxy` and add `P` to the `RewriteRule` flags.